# Import saved Processes (pid) as ProcessChild class

Tags: c#, .net, windows, inheritance, process

Goal is to remember a list of external processes if my application is closed in the meantime. Therefore process pids are saved into a file and imported on application launch. Now the problem arises:

As long as process ids should be imported of type [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-6.0) there is no problem as I can use Process.GetProcessById:

```
public List<Process> GetKnownProcesses()
{
    int[] saved_ids = { 1, 2, 3 };
    List<Process> known_processes = new List<Process>();
    for (int id in save_ids)
    {
        known_processes.Add(Process.GetProcessById(id)); //No Exception handling to keep it simple
    }
    return known_processes;
}
```

However in its current form I have to use a childclass of Process.

```
public class ProcessChild : Process
{
    //extending some functionality
}

public List<ProcessChild> GetKnownProcesses()
{
    int[] saved_ids = { 1, 2, 3 };
    List<ProcessChild> known_processes = new List<ProcessChild>();
    for (int id in save_ids)
    {
        known_processes.Add(Process.GetProcessById(id)); //ERROR: I would have to Downcast here
    }
    return known_processes;
}
```

So this clearly won't work as I would have to downcast Process into ProcessChild. Copying properties from parent to child is also of no use, because several Properties are read / get only. Is there an efficient way to resolve this issue, without writting my own GetProcessById method? Maybe there is another way of setting certain properties and calling an update method of some sort?

Comment: Favor composition over inheritance. Why would you need a ChildProcess class inheriting a framework class? Can't you create like a ProcessInfo class that has a Process _property_ along with your extra properties? How does your code otherwise instantiate a ProcessChild? And what do you do to detect that a PID is recycled?

Comment: FYI: Keep in mind that when a process exits or is being killed, that process id of that now former process is free to be assigned to another newly started process. Thus, how do you know if a process with a given id is actually the process you are interested in? Who knows what happened with regards to processes running, ending, being started etc... between closing your application and starting it anew. This looks quite unreliable to me.

Comment: @CodeCaster PID is one of the main components to get the process on import. In reality a hash of process startime + process id is stored and imported and checked vs existing processes. Currently not mentioned here to keep it more simple. The child class sadly is deeply backed into the project, rewritting the process as a Property would be a big time investment in its current stage.

Comment: Gotcha on the first part. You could convert ProcessChild it to a facade, like `public int PID => _process.PID`, because what exactly will the callers use from the Process base class anyway? I don't know how trivial it would be to create your own GetProcessByID() that clones a Process into a ChildProcess.